# How do I run Tinytest on an android device for testing package for meteor-cordova app?

Tags: cordova, meteor, tinytest

I want to test cordova specific feature of meteor-package using Tinytest on android device. So I have tried the steps found [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#testing).

My test file `cordova-test.js` contains only the following

```
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
   Tinytest.add("cordova-package - First Test ", function(test) {
       test.equal(1, 1, "Equal test");
   });
}
```

My `package.js` have the following `Package.onTest()`

```
 Package.onTest(function(api) {
  api.use(['tinytest','test-helpers']);
  api.use('sujith3g:cordova-package');
  api.addFiles('tests/cordova-test.js', "client");
});
```

I have used `meteor test-packages --android-device ./` command to exceute the tests.
 Then it gave me

> Testing in progress..

message on the android device for a long time, It is not even starting the test. Do I need to do anything else for testing a package on android device using Tinytest ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all combinations of `meteor test-packages`, I got it working on android device by using this.

`meteor test-packages --android-device ./ --mobile-server http://192.168.1.4:3000`

The mobile-server(`--mobile-server http://<host>:<port>`) argument is required for it to work on android device